# How can i start my app written with libgdx on my android device?

Tags: android, eclipse, device, apk, libgdx

I have written some codelines with libgdx in eclipse and want to run them on my android device.(It's a tablet)
But i cant find out how to do this.

I even cant run it on the android emulator provided by the android sdk. I get an error that the app stopped unexpectedly.
The app is working fine with the desktop launcher...

I hope someone can explain me how to get it working on the emulator or on my android device.

I saw somewhere that simply connecting my device via usb should be enough that eclipse is able to create an temporary app on the device, but this also didnt work.

Regards

Comment: How did you build your project ? and please post your logcat as well

Comment: @user1743625: This link may be useful for you, see fully, especially at the end of the post, http://chrismweb.com/2011/10/18/how-to-start-creating-android-games-using-the-libgdx-game-development-framework/

Comment: http://nopaste.info/97a2a95f21.html thats my logcat log

Comment: is there any problem with permission?

Comment: as you can see class 'com.gebe.linerunner.Game' is not found , on your android project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export is your main project marked?

Comment: hey thank you for your answer, it wasnt marked. now i marked it tried it again but still same error

Comment: well tried it again, i cleaned the projects refreshed them and it worked!! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1st of all, download SamsungKies[latest], to get and install proper USB Drivers. Its important that it should be the latest, cuz there was a bug in the previous versions.

Now that you have the drivers, simply connect your device to your machine IN USB DEBUGGING MODE.

Go to your main activity, and run.

If it launches in an emulator, close the emulator, and again in main activity, select run configurations -> Android Applications -> target -> always prompt to pick device.

Run again, and it should install and run in your phone/tablet.

NOTE:The activity closes in emulator because, by default, the emulator doesn't support OpenGLES emulation, its too heavy for your CPU.

i know its kinda late, but i hope it helps others:)